# How could i change the angular cli date to local time zone?

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I use `ng serve` and when I change some file, Angular CLI will display date like this

```
Date: 2018-08-26T13:55:06.527Z - Hash: be4766fc643be6692ac3 - Time: 126ms
```

But the `Date:2018-08-26T13:55:06.527Z` is not my local time.

How could I change the angular cli date to local time zone?
My country's time zone is UTC+8 in Taiwan

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/6fa9c2f5af45859fb9c0f51ce70686eb4c6ac473/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/utilities/stats.ts#L54-L57) I think it is impossible:

```
export function generateBuildStats(hash: string, time: number, colors: boolean): string {
  const w = (x: string) => colors ? bold(white(x)) : x;
  return `Date: ${w(new Date().toISOString())} - Hash: ${w(hash)} - Time: ${w('' + time)}ms`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **Date().toISOString()** in the follwing stats.js with **Date().toString()**

node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\stats.js